# How to search for posts containing images?

Tags: support

Is there a way to search for posts containing images?

I did not find a way, but it would be practical to have some ...

Comment: Please have a look at this related meta Math.SE post: [What is the efficient way to search post with pictures/images?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9402/what-is-the-efficient-way-to-search-post-with-pictures-images)